# miragejs '[WDS] Disconnected!' instantly

Tags: webpack-dev-server, miragejs

If I `createServer` with **miragejs**, WDS (Webpack Dev Server) get disconnected.

[image: Disconnected]

if I disable mirages mock server, WDS works I expected.

[image: Live Reloading enabled]

Here is full call stack of `[WDS] Disconnected!`

[image: Call Stack]

#### src/index.tsx

```
import { mockServer } from './server';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    mockServer({ environment: "development" });
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <App />
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
     </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### src/server.js

```
import { createServer, Response, Model } from 'miragejs';
export const mockServer = ({ environment = 'test' }) => {

    createServer({
        environment,
        routes() {
            this.namespace = "api";
            this.post('/user/login', (schema, request) => {
                return new Response(200, { }, { id: "admin@gmail.com", email: "qwerty", token: "Edovbkeyd2943kd3" });
            });
        },
    });
}
export default mockServer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by migrating from `React Hot Loader` to `React Fast Refresh`.

[image: success]

I recommend to read '[Moving towards next step](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#moving-towards-next-step)' of `React Hot Loader`. `React Hot Loader` is slowly replace to `React Fast Refresh`.